# sum up a list using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

For the following data -

```
int[] array = {56,67,78,89,90,12,23};
List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Why is there a difference in the below:

```
int sum1 = Arrays.stream(array).sum();

int sum2 = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Why cant the second option be `list.stream().sum()` without the extra conversion?

Comment: What if it was a `Stream<Foo>`? What would `sum` mean in that case?

Comment: Also, what is `array` in your first statement? Could you share the complete details.

Comment: The difference is that `Array.stream(array)` and `list.stream()` return different types: `Array.stream(array)` returns `IntStream`, `list.stream()` returns `Stream<Integer>`

Comment: `new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array))` does not really work…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the confusing part is here, because
Arrays.stream(array) and list.stream() are not producing the same result.. those return actually completely different streams.

the long answer is:

when you do this:

`Arrays.stream(array)` you get back a `IntStream` that is basically a stream of integers, so that objects has a method `sum()` that let you do the addition acumulative of all its elements..

but not every stream of T allows to concate Ts so that method is not avaliable in a normal stream, one option is to pass the stream over a function that convert those into a new stream... that is what mapToInt does.